# How to see the Bullets I'm shooting on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, javascript-objects

Again im having a Problem with my Canvas. I'm currently programming a Javascript Space Shooter.

I created a Bullet Class and want the Spaceship to be able to shoot Bullets. The Problem is: There a no Errors but also, no Bullets. I'm not totally sure if they are just not drawn or I just can't see them.

If you could help me, you would really help me a lot:

The relevant Files (main.js, held.js) i've uploaded to my Git: 
https://github.com/nemoxdelight/First_Game

Sorry for the German Comments, but it makes it a lot easier for me sometimes :P

I think the Problem is somewhere in here in the held.js:

```
//Kugeln
this.leerTaste = false;
this.isShooting = false;
this.kugeln = [];
this.aktuelleKugel = 0;
//Wenn wir einen neuen Held erstellen, werden 20 Schuss "geladen"
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    this.kugeln[this.kugeln.length] = new Kugel();
}
}
//Held Objekt
Held.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.tasteCheck();
    this.held_nase_x = this.held_x + 10;
    this.held_nase_y = this.held_y;
    this.schussCheck();
    this.kugeln_zeichnen();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.farbe_ball;
    ctx.arc(this.held_x, this.held_y, this.groese_ball, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.arc(this.held_x - 17, this.held_y, this.groese_ball - 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.shadowBlur = this.blur_ball;
    ctx.shadowColor = this.farbe_blur_ball;
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.shadowColor = "transparent";
};
Held.prototype.tasteCheck = function() {
    if (this.hochTaste == true) {
        this.held_y -= this.speed;
    }
    if (this.rechtsTaste == true) {
        this.held_x += this.speed;
    }
    if (this.linksTaste == true) {
        this.held_x -= this.speed;
    }
    if (this.runterTaste == true) {
        this.held_y += this.speed;
    }
};
//Da unsere Kugeln nur in x-Richtung vom Held aus fliegen, sind sie alle größer als 0.          Der Ursprung findet sich beim Held.
Held.prototype.kugeln_zeichnen = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.kugeln.length; i++) {
        if (this.kugeln[i].held_x >= 0) {
            this.kugeln[i].draw();
        }
    }
}
Held.prototype.schussCheck = function() {
    if (this.leerTaste && !this.isShooting) {
        this.isShooting = true;
        this.kugeln[this.aktuelleKugel].geschossen(this.held_nase_x, this.held_nase_y);
        this.aktuelleKugel++;
        //Wiederverwendne der Kugeln
        if (this.aktuelleKugel >= this.kugeln.length) {
            this.aktuelleKugel = 0;
        }
    } else if (!this.leerTaste) {
        this.isShooting = false;
    }
}
//KUGEL FUNKTIONEN
function Kugel() {
    this.groese_kugel = 3;
    //Kugeln aufbewahren
    this.drawX = -20;
    this.drawY = 0;
}
Kugel.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.drawX += 3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ff99ff';
    ctx.arc(this.drawX, this.drawY, this.groese_kugel, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    if (this.drawX > width) {
        this.drawX = -20;
    }
};
Kugel.prototype.geschossen = function(startX, startY) {
    //Sagt an was erlaubt ist.
    this.drawX = startX;
    this.drawY = startY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Held.prototype.kugeln_zeichnen = function () {
for (var i = 0; i < this.kugeln.length; i++){
    if(this.kugeln[i].held_x >= 0) {
        this.kugeln[i].draw();
       }
   }
}
```

There is no field called `held_x`, at least not in the constructor of `Kugel`. Maybe you wanted to use something like

```
Held.prototype.kugeln_zeichnen = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.kugeln.length; i++){   
        if(this.kugeln[i].drawX - this.held_nase_x > -20){
            this.kugeln[i].draw();
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, do you really mean `if(laeuft = true){` in `main.js line 46`?

Comment: `if(laeuft = true)` Looks like he means `==`.

Comment: Wow, thank you! No it works and i also see my Bullets now :) Thank you also for pointing out the if-Error i corrected it now. Apparently i have a weakness for Bad Coding.

Comment: @user1478242: You should definitely stop switching languages in your code. Choose either German or English, otherwise you'll ask yourself often "did I call this method `zeichnen` or `draw`? Is this object called `kugel` or `bullet`?

Comment: Yes, i think English would definitely be the better Decision. Thanks again for the fast help!